Prove that these two definitions of convex are equivalent
Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Given the following two definitions of convexity of $f$, prove that (i) implies (ii):
(i) $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \ge f(y) + f'(y)(x - y)$
(ii) $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}, \forall \lambda \in [0, 1] : f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(y)$

First I saw that (i) is: $$f'(y) \leq \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} \,\,\, (*)$$ So the slope from $y$ to a greater point $x$ is always greater than the slope of only $y$.
I have tried writing $f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) = f(y+\lambda(y-x))$ as $f(y)$ plus, so to speak, the sum of all $f'(y + \epsilon \cdot n) \cdot \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and $n$ needs to be defined correctly of course. So just the "starting-point" $f(y)$ and then every point with it's slope until we reach $f(y+\lambda(y-x))$. That slope, I would estimate using $(*)$ and get an inequality. But this doesn't work since I would need to use (*) on the actual points $x$ and $y$, but that doesn't work of course.

I can't come up with a different attempt and the other questions on the internet don't have a derivative in them. They are all different definitions of convexity than the ones here.

in (i) set $y:= \lambda \hat x+ (1-\lambda) \hat y$ and $x:=\hat x, \hat y$, where $\hat x$, $\hat y$ referes to points in property (ii)

honestly, this was certainly asked before on this site. I could not find a duplicate, though.

@daw I don't understand. Set $x$ to x^? Or to y^? Or both? I tried both and I just get a long inequality which does not me lead to anything useful

We want to show that i) implies ii).  We assume that ii) does not hold true.  It exists then two points $a, b$ and a scalar $\mu \in (0, 1)$ such that
$$
f(x_\mu) > \mu f(a) +(1 -\mu)f(b)
$$
with $x_\mu = \mu a +(1 -\mu) b$.  We want to show that this is impossible.  We first apply i) to $a$ and $x_\mu$ and then to $b$ and $x_\mu$.  We have
$$\label{eq:1}
f(a) \geq f(x_\mu) +f'(x_\mu)(a -x_\mu)
= f(x_\mu) +(1 -\mu)f'(x_\mu)(a -b)
\tag{$\ast$}
$$
and
$$\label{eq:2}
f(b) \geq f(x_\mu) +f'(x_\mu)(b -x_\mu)
= f(x_\mu) -\mu f'(x_\mu)(a -b)
\tag{$\ast\ast$}.
$$
We multiply \eqref{eq:1} by $\mu$ and \eqref{eq:2} by $1 -\mu$ and then take their sum.  We obtain
$$
\mu f(a) +(1 -\mu)f(b) \geq f(x_\mu)
$$
which contradicts the initial assumption.

I don't understand how we obtain $()$. Since $b-x_{\mu}$ is negative, we actually would substract something. By replacing it with the derivative, we substract something smaller than before, so the result would be bigger. In $(*)$ we have everything $\geq 0$, so that works, but in $()$ I don't see it working!

Being positive or negative does not count; it's a computation.  You have $b -x_\mu = b -\mu a -(1 -\mu)b = \mu (b -a)$.
